# Is there any option to edit the quick links without having to go to edit mode in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, quick-links

I need to create a quick links webpart which is capable of editing the links without having to edit the webpart. Is this possible? Am I missing any out of the box feature?

Answer (score 0):

you can use list and WP for displaying list items with HyperLink, Links WebPart must be edited always in Edit mode for adding new records. because they are saved in the WebPart and with Editing you are creating new version and it's visible, who edited this page.